# Attribute updating when using text_field, but not select or checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to update a model using a selectbox:

```
f.select :currency, options_for_select([["please select", ""], "DKR", "SEK", "EURO"]), :selected => :currency
```

I have tried different variations of `select_tag`, `select`, etc.

However, this is not working, but when I use a `text_field`, the attribute is saved fine to the database:

```
 f.text_field :currency
```

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to say what the value is for each of those names:

`["DKR", "dkr"], ["SEK", "sek"]` etc...`

Comment: You are absolutely right - but I would swear I tried that already - Only problem now is that selected => :currency don't work

Comment: changed it to this; <%= f.select(:currency, options_for_select([["Select One", ""], ["DKR","dkr"], ["SEK","sek"], ["EURO","euro"]],@program.currency)) %> and now selected value works